# c++: The order of iterating through std::hash_map

Tags: c++, stl, hashmap

Iterating through a map is guaranteed to be done by order (according to the defined comparison function).

What about a hash_map for example, is there a guaranteed order when iterating through this from `begin()` to `end()`?

Comment: I think this is the first time I've seen the stl tag used where it is actually appropriate.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Is it appropriate? AFAIK `hash_map` was not part of the STL...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: It wasn't in Stepanov's original proposal, but it must have been added at some point between then and 1997. Because it's [here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html), and none of the updates [here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/whats_new.html), the oldest of which is from 1997, mention its addition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `hash_map` or the standard equivalent `std::unordered_map` is an *unordered* container.